# Sending Zip file to Client via Response with DotNetZip

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, response, dotnetzip

this is my code

```
    private void sendToClient(Dictionary<string, string> reportDic)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        String ReadmeText = "some text";
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + "filename.zip");
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddEntry("Readme.txt", ReadmeText);
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.Close();
    }
```

at this point I'm simply trying to return a zip file with the readme.txt document inside the zip with the words "some text" inside the document.

What I get is a zipfile named filename.zip(expected) with a document readme.txt(expected) with no text inside of the doucment(unexpected).

This code is almost verbatim from the example [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Examples).  Which makes me thing other people have run into this exact problem.

My end goal is to do something like this.

```
    private void sendToClient(Dictionary<string, string> reportDic)
    {
        Response.BufferOutput = false;
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-dispostion", "filename=text.zip");
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        Response.Charset = "";
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (string key in reportDic.Keys)
            {
                zip.AddEntry(key, reportDic[key]);
            }
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.Close();
    }
```

add three strings as files to the zip file, but I'll settle for getting the example working for now.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

--UPDATE--
This should work, in fact if I copy it into a new project, it works just as advertised, I must have a toxic mix of dlls or some corruption in my project, that is obscure or something.  Wonderful.

Comment: I get a bad zip header error when I try to open with iZarc but it opens and gives me the empty file, also this zip will not open with the xp compression utility.

Comment: I've tried the "AddEntry" method with a string, with a byte[] and a stream.  No good.

Comment: Jim, did you get this sorted?

Comment: Cheeso, sorry I haven't got back to you, I had to move forward with another project that should only take a day or two.  I never got this problem solved...instead I make the poor user click 4 buttons, but I needed to get something done quickly because I had testers waiting on the output...I'll be able to go back either tomorrow or Monday, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

don't use

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

instead, use

```
Response.Close();
```

If you use the former, you  will get HTML junk appended to the bottom of your zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in the AddFile method with some dummy text = I think this is required.

Comment: I just tried this, it seems as though doing something like zip.addFile("somefile.txt") gives me a file not found exception

Comment: addFile looks like the way to add a file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to on CodePlex seems to say the `AddEntry` method reads data from a stream. You're just passing in a string - maybe you could try creating a `StringReader` to look at your ReadmeText string, and pass this in instead?

Comment: it seems as though it's overloaded to take a string

Comment: oh right, I haven't looked at the actual API, just at the example on the web page.

Comment: I haven't seen the API at all, I've gone from the examples and they are poor, or at the very least I'm too stupid to figure them out.  I don't know where to go from here other than find an alternative solution, like use something else.